# Como usar um estilo externo(pronto) de CSS no código HTML?

Tags: html, css

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, tenho um código *HTML* que estou usando para aprender nas aulas do meu curso. Então após a aula de *CSS* quis usar um dos modelos utilizados durante a explicação no meu código. Coloquei a pasta com o estilo dentro da pasta que o *HTML* está. Logo, eu escrevi o seguinte código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Loja X-Sobre</title>
    <!-- Comentário -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Loja X</h1>
    <h2>Bem-vindo à Loja X, a sua loja de eletro-eletrônicos!</h2>
    <ol start="10"type="I">
        <li>Confira nossas promoções.</li>
        <li>Fique por dentro de nossos lançamentos.</li>
        <li>Veja nosso catálogo.</li>
        <li>Faça logo a sua lista de compras.</li>
    </ol>
    <h3>Ache o Olie</h3>
    <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
    <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
    <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
    <p>Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
    <p>Texto Texto Texto<sup>Texto</sup><!-- Superior /-->Texto <sub>Texto</sub><!-- Inferior /--> Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
    Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
    Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto <mark>Texto</mark><!-- Marca texto Amarelo /--> Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
    Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
    Texto Texto Texto Texto <del>Texto</del><!-- Risca texto /--> Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto <b>Texto</b><!-- Negrito /--> TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
    Texto Texto Texto Texto <ins>Texto</ins><!-- Sublinha texto /--> Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
    Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto
    Texto Texto Texto <strong>Texto</strong><!-- Negrito /--> Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto TextoTexto Texto Texto Texto Texto <em>Texto</em><!-- Itálico /--> Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto Texto</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Creio que seja algo no `head`. Podem me ajudar ?

O código CSS abaixo:

```
========================================================================
/* Stylesheet 2: */
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #d14836;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

header {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 26px;    
}

header h1 {
    margin:0;
    line-height: 50px;
}

nav {
    width: 190px;
    float: right;
}

#main {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font: 80% Verdana;
}

#main h1, #main h2 {
    color: #d14836;
}

aside {
    background-color: #F6DAD7;
    color: #d14836;
    padding: 10px;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#menulist {
    padding:0;
    font: 16px verdana;
}

.menuitem {
    width: 155px;
    background-color: #d14836;
    border: 1px solid #d14836;
    border-radius: 40px;
    color: #ffffff;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menuitem:nth-child(2) {
background-color:white;
color: #d14836;
font-weight:bold;
}

.menuitem:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #d14836;
}

a {
    color: #d14836;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Você quer baixar um CSS de terceiros e utilizar em site? Se for isso, basta utilizar a URL do CSS no atributo `href` no elemento `link`. Ps.: Não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Então, eu estava na aula. O professor disponibilizou uns estilos de css. No caso eu escolhi o que tem o nome: estilo.css

Mas algo deu errado porque no código de exemplo ele é ótimo mas no meu código  ele nem apareceu.

A e eu não entendi exatamente o que quis dizer com "href" no elemento "link"

Eu quis justamente usar o href para chamar o css que está dentro da minha pasta.

<DOCKTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Loja X-Sobre</title>
    <!-- Comentário -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo2.css">
</head>

Comment: O href do link do seu .CSS esta errado. Deve ser tipo assim href="nomedapasta/estilo2.css"

Comment: Não deve ser isso. Tentei praticamente todas as pastas que podia e ainda assim não resolveu.

Comment: `CTRL + ALT + J` -> Aba `Network`  -> press `F5`, veja se o arquivo foi carregado.

Comment: aproveita e coloca o código `css` na sua questão também.

Comment: Esse atalho que você colocou não fez nada no meu pc. Pelo menos não que tenha percebido.

Comment: Relativamente ao teu ficheiro que tem o HTML, onde está o ficheiro CSS? Se o ficheiro está a ser incluido, o problema seguinte é o HTML nao corresponder ao CSS (e vice-versa), no CSS tens uma regra assim por exemplo, `header h1 { ...` mas no HTML, o único `<h1>` que tens não tem um *pai* `<header>`.

Comment: @Leite é por ai mesmo! NADA, do que está declarado no CSS exite no HTML, ai não tem como funcionar hahaha. No CSS tem header, nav, footer, aside, e no HTML não tem essas tag para receber os estilos, ai não tem como mesmo...

Comment: Sim, meu html está pobre. Mas o css funcionou. Vou estudar mais para entender melhor. Mesmo assim muito obrigado. 
A questão foi resolvida mexendo nas pastas. parece que o css tinha 1 pasta a mais e mais interna do que o código do html. 1 caminho a mais que o html entende ?

Comment: Não está pobre não, está normal para quem está a dar os primeiros passos. Aqui a questão é que o **css** que o teu professor criou foi para um **html** que ele tinha, com uma estrutura diferente da que tu tens no teu, dai alguns dos estilos do **css** não estarem presentes. Nesta fase de aprendizagem ainda não é fácil ver como o **html** e o **css** se ligam, quando isso acontecer vai ser instantâneo perceber este tipo de problemas, mas haverá sempre outros mais complicados para resolver. Boa sorte com os estudos, e não deixes de colocar perguntas que estamos cá para ajudar

Comment: Gabriel vc está no caminho certo, me desculpe se soei desrespeitoso. O que eu queria dizer é que se no HTML vc não tem o elemento que vc fez a referência no CSS, não tem como o estilo ser aplicado, o elemento tem que existir e ser referenciado nos dois arquivos. Boa sorte com os estudos!

Comment: Deverá colocar a resposta na area de baixo e eliminar a resposta do local da pergunta

Comment: Primeiramente Hugo Não foi desrespeitoso não. Eu que não tenho muito conhecimento e não estava entendendo o que você tinha falado. 

Amadeu vou fazer isso. Só estava achando que bastava:" O resolvido no problema".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use um `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="exemplo.css">`
dentro do `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido com uma mudança nas pastas onde o código html se encontra. Com esse ajuste pude diminuir em 1x o caminho do CSS e assim pude utilizalo de forma correta no meu código.

Desde já, obrigado aos que me ajudaram. Até a próxima!